# vertical scroll bar in report doesn't show up in tile in Dashboard Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vertical-scroll

I have been trying to pin the Power BI report in dashboard when publishing to power BI but the vertical scroll bar in report doesn't show up in dashboard. I am able to use the scroll bar in report but when I pin that in dashboard, I can't see the scroll bar in that tile in dashboard.

Comment: Please share screenshots of the visual in both the report and dashboard and describe the issue in the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use pages, as per the Power BI, after publishing to Power BI, only the section visible inside the Gridlines in the Desktop is visible.

For this problem, you can use multiple pages, after publishing, you would be able to switch between pages.

Hope it answers your question, Prashant!